# Опционы, вероятности

Tags: python-3.x

Работаю с опционами, там есть такое условие

> в каждый из моментов времени она уменьшается на 7-10% с вероятностью 40-70%

Как это посчитать?

```
import random
number = random.uniform(0.07, 0.1)
down = random.uniform(0.4, 0.7)
print(number)
print(down)
```

Comment: Если случайное число от 0.0 до 1.0 окажется меньше или равно чем down, то нужное число умножаем на (1.0 - number)

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint
opt = 500
while opt > 0:  # В каждый из моментов времени
    if 40 <= randint(1, 100) <= 70:  # с вероятностью 40-70%
        opt -= (opt * (randint(7, 10) / 100))  # уменьшается на 7-10%
    continue
```